# Can't invoke function when changing Date property in DatePicker - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a date picker in my view:

```
<DatePicker MinimumDate="{Binding Today}" Date="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

And in my viewModel class i have these two properties:

```
private DateTime selectedDate;
    public DateTime SelectedDate
    {
        get { return selectedDate; }
        set
        {
            selectedDate = value;             
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedDate));
            //ExecuteFunction();
        }
    }

    private DateTime today;
    public DateTime Today
    {
        get { return today; }
        set
        {
            today = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Today));
            ExecuteFunction();
        }
    }
```

I want to execute a function when my SelectedDate changes (when the user chooses the date) but i get this error:

[image]

However, i can execute the same function when its only in the "Today" property (i did that for testing). Anyone know why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: Not enough information to know why. Put try-catch (Exception ex) around the call to ExecuteFunction, then use a breakpoint to examine `ex`. Does it have an "inner exception"? If so, add to question text of inner exception. **Regardless, sounds like `ExecuteFunction` does something unusual.  What happens if you comment out the entire contents of `ExecuteFunction`, so that it does nothing?** ALSO, **When** do you get that error message? When page loads? When someone clicks on picker? When picker closes?

Comment: Good point, sorry. The exception is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". That function "ExecuteFunction" was trying to access the value of the variable SelectedDate and i dont know why when its the first time that it executes (when the page loads) that exception happens. So i made that when its the first time the page loads the function will not execute, it will only when the value changes. I dont know if this is the best way but i will post in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have isolated the problem, a better fix is to change ExecuteFunction so it copes with a bad date. OR don't call ExecuteFunction when the date is bad.

Several possible ways to fix:

1. Try-catch inside ExecuteFunction.
2. set a breakpoint, find out what value that bad date is. Add a test to skip ExecuteFunction when that value is seen.
3. Since it happens during InitializeComponent, that means xaml is setting it - almost certainly setting it to the value it already has - so you could change SelectedDate setter to:

```cs
set
{
    if (selectedDate != value)
    {
        selectedDate = value;             
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedDate));
        ExecuteFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you! I will mark your answer the correct one instead of mine

Answer (score 1):

This only happens when the page loads for the first time with this code the function is not be called when it loads for the first time.

```
private bool First { get; set; } = true;

    private DateTime selectedDate;
    public DateTime SelectedDate
    {
        get { return selectedDate; }
        set
        {
            selectedDate= value;             
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedDate));

            if (!First)
            {
                ExecuteFunction();
            }
            else
            {
                First = false;
            }
        }
    }
```